# Python - I need this key , value accessed outside of for loop. How can I make this global

Tags: python, dictionary

Here's my sample code :
    for key,value in application_list.items():
    where application_list is a JSON.
I need this key and value, later outside of the scope of for loop like this:

```
for key,value in application_list.items():
  .....
  ......
  more computations
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(key))
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: declare some variable say `x` as `None` outside the `for` loop and assign the key to `x` inside the loop

Comment: Surely there will be many keys and values. Which would you want?

Comment: I need the first key which is a timestamp value from which i want to compute the end_time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a specific key you want to store for later use, simply assign to a variable, e.g. `x`, as below:

```
for key, value in application_list.items():

    # computations

    x = key  # for your chosen key dependent on your conditions

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x))
```

If you want to save the first key only:

```
for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(application_list.items(), 1):

    # computations

    if idx == 1:
        x = key  # for your chosen key dependent on your conditions

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x))
```

Comment: for key,value in application_list.items():  
    x = key[0]   
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x))  
dt_formatted = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  
time_source.append(dt_formatted)  
start_time = time_source[0]  
t_end = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(minutes=1)  
time_end = t_end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  
print(dt_formatted, time_end) - # Output is 1969-12-31 19:00:01 1969-12-31 19:10:01, whereas my key[0] from my json is - 2018-02-18 20:08:36

Comment: I need the first key which is a timestamp value from which i want to compute the end_time.

Comment: You are applying this logic to a dictionary and in Python there is no guarantee that items() will be returned in a particular order.

Comment: @Jesuisme, this is true. But since user says he needs "first key" I have to assume his dictionary is a `collections.OrderedDict`. Otherwise, we need more clarity.